# Swift - unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter, nsnotifications

I have a simple `NSNotification` set up on my Swift project.

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "serviceAccessChanged", name:"LocationAccessChangedNotification", object: nil)
```

I've also tried...

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "serviceAccessChanged:", name:"LocationAccessChangedNotification", object: nil)
```

The method called looks like so.

```
private func serviceAccessChanged() {
    println("serviceAccessChanged")
}
```

When the notification is made I receive the following error.

```
-[CoolApp.HomeViewController serviceAccessChanged]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fc91324bba0
```

What's wrong and how do I fix this?

Comment: Same error after adding the `:`

Comment: The class inherits from `UIViewController`. Isn't that inherited from `NSObject`?

Comment: take out the private then you use the first line with the :

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Private functions are not exposed to Objective C, and this is why you get this exception. Make this method accessible, and use the `serviceAccessChanged` selector.

Comment: I planned on it. SO has that waiting period.

Answer (score 1):

Just mark your private method with @objc

```
@objc private func serviceAccessChanged() {
    println("serviceAccessChanged")
}
```